# Get project location for Xcode extension

Tags: swift, xcode-workspace, xcode-extension

I'm working on an Xcode extension, which needs to get the project path, i.e. the path of the project/workspace from which you run the extension command which I'm making. I've tried something like this:

```
let workspace = NSWorkspace.shared()
let path = workspace.absolutePathForApplication(withBundleIdentifier: Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleIdentifier"] as! String)
```

but it just returns nil. I have also tried getting it via the FileManager, but it just returns a path of the extension.

Answer (score 0):

App Extensions are always sandboxed, so they don’t have arbitrary filesystem access.

For security, Xcode Source Editor Extensions are also only passed the text of the file for which a user has invoked an action, not the path to the file itself or a sandbox extension allowing access to it or its containing project.